# Serilog configuration for Oracle database

Tags: c#, asp.net, serilog

I created a table in my database and i want to store my log information in this table. I used that code which is located here https://github.com/lucascebertin/Serilog.Sinks.Oracle. More specific i used :

```
var connectionString =
      "user id=system;password=oracle;data source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 49161)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME = xe)))";

  // If you choose to use the trigger just pass string.Empty in function name argument (tableSpaceAndFunctionName)

      var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
          .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
          .WriteTo.Oracle(cfg => 
              cfg.WithSettings(connectionString)
              .UseBurstBatch() // or if you want to use PeriodicBatch, call .UsePeriodicBatch()
              .CreateSink())
          .CreateLogger();
```

How can i define the table and the column where i want to store my log information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an optional Parameter `tableSpaceAndTableName` in the `WithSettings(connectionString)` call.

Edit:

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
          .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
          .WriteTo.Oracle(cfg => 
              cfg.WithSettings(connectionString, tableSpaceAndTableName: "MyLogTable")
              .UseBurstBatch() // or if you want to use PeriodicBatch, call .UsePeriodicBatch()
              .CreateSink())
          .CreateLogger();
```

Edit 2:

For adding new columns:

```
const string column = "ADDITIONALDATACOLUMN";
var columnOptions = new ColumnOptions
{
    AdditionalDataColumns = new List<DataColumn>
    {
        new DataColumn(column , typeof(string))
    }
};
```

and pass it to the `columnOptions` parameter in `WithSettings`

```
new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.WithProperty("ADDITIONALDATACOLUMN", "MyValue")  /* uncomment this line if you want to store a "constant value" */
      .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
      .WriteTo.Oracle(cfg =>
          cfg.WithSettings(logConnectionString, columnOptions: columnOptions)
          .UseBurstBatch()
          .CreateSink())
      .CreateLogger();
```

You can add this as a static value if you pass it via `Enrich.WithProperty` or add it in you log messages should in theory also set the column (didn't tested it) depends on your use case what you need.

Comment: I used that parameter , but i didn't get the expected result, the log information in which column will be stored ?

Comment: As written on the page you linked it will be the message column. But you specify additional stuff with the ColumnOptions which you can also pass.

Comment: thanks a lot @pr177 , i will try to solve it :)

Comment: But it's CLOB you have to convert it to nvarchar, but that's documented very well :)

Comment: hello @pr177, if i want to add some new columns, how can i achieve that ?

Comment: Hmm, maybe you have to share more details. Normally there shouldn't be any difference when it comes to logging between these having a console and winforms. What means you can't do it? Do you have any error / exception? How does it behave?

Comment: I found it, thanks pr177, i needed to do some updates in my project packages. Now works fine. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Very cool! Would be nice if you mark my response as answer! Wish you a good time

Comment: do you have any idea about this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69939405/serilog-log-different-data-to-different-places?noredirect=1#comment123632142_69939405