# Serilog : log different data to different places

Tags: c#, oracle, serilog

I want to log my whole data in a file and log only the errors in my oracle database. I'm using the below code but it's not working.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()          
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose().WriteTo.File("logs/myLog.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Minute)
            .MinimumLevel.Error().WriteTo.Oracle(cfg =>
                cfg.WithSettings(logConnectionString, tableSpaceAndTableName: "MY_TABLE")
                .UseBurstBatch(true, 1000, true, 1)
                .CreateSink())
            .CreateLogger();
```

In this case, i log only error data both in file and oracle database. How must i configure the above code, to store the whole data in a file and the error data in database?

Comment: "*but it's not working*" is not a technical description of a problem.

Comment: I think that my problem and my description are enough understandable.

Comment: @Fatman123 no they aren't. Is anything written to the database or not? Is anything written to the log file or not? Are the same things written in both? As for the actual problem, don't `File()` and `Oracle()` have a `restrictedToMinimumLevel` parameter already?

Comment: ok i agree with that , give me one moment to add some more details.

Comment: Those details should include where `Oracle()` comes from, what package was used. Oracle isn't that popular, no matter what its salespeople say. Serilog itself has no Oracle sink. Which packages did you use?

Comment: i'm using Serilog, Serilog.Sinks.File, Serilog.Sinks.Oracle packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost all sinks have a `restrictedToMinimumLevel` parameter. There's no `Serilog.Sinks.Oracle` project in the Serilog Github repo so I assume you use [Serilog.Sinks.Oracle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.Oracle/). The [Oracle()](https://github.com/lucascebertin/Serilog.Sinks.Oracle/blob/master/src/Serilog.Sinks.Oracle/Serilog.Sinks.Oracle/Extensions/LoggerConfigurationOracle.cs#L12) method accepts a `restrictedToMinimumLevel` parameter as well.

You can change your code to :

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()          
            .WriteTo.File("logs/myLog.txt", 
                          rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Minute, 
                          restrictedToMinimumLevel:LogEventLevel.Verbose)
            .WriteTo.Oracle(cfg =>
                    cfg.WithSettings(logConnectionString, tableSpaceAndTableName: "MY_TABLE")
                    .UseBurstBatch(true, 1000, true, 1)
                    .CreateSink(),
                restrictedToMinimumLevel:LogEventLevel.Error )
            .CreateLogger();
```

Configuring database logging typically takes more code than this, so it's a good idea to extract the code to a different method. You'll probably want to use additional columns to extract common attributes like categories, activity IDs etc so you don't have to parse the JSON payload to find specific events:

```
ILogEventSink ConfigureOracle(BatchLoggerConfiguration cfg)
{
    const string column = "ADDITIONALDATACOLUMN";
    var columnOptions = new ColumnOptions
    {
        AdditionalDataColumns = new List<DataColumn>
        {
            new DataColumn(column , typeof(string))
        }
    };
    return cfg.WithSettings(logConnectionString, tableSpaceAndTableName: "MY_TABLE")
                    .UseBurstBatch(true, 1000, true, 1)
                    .CreateSink();
}

...

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()          
            .WriteTo.File("logs/myLog.txt", 
                          rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Minute, 
                          restrictedToMinimumLevel:LogEventLevel.Verbose)
            .WriteTo.Oracle(ConfigureOracle,LogEventLevel.Error )
            .CreateLogger();
```

**Organizing database logging code**

I also log to a database. Putting everything into a single expression may be fashionable but the resulting code can quickly become too hard to read and maintain. Fluent APIs aren't always a good idea.

In this case, one almost always needs to specify extra columns to hold common properties like categories and activity IDs, perhaps even customer IDs. This means specifying extra columns. No matter the database product, querying the raw JSON data is more expensive than querying materialized and indexed columns.

It will take some experimentation until one get a table you can actually use for troubleshooting. The database logging configuration should be extracted into a separate a separate method, if not a separate *file*. Otherwise `Startup.cs` or, in .NET 6, `Program.cs`, will become an unreadable mess.

Comment: @Fatman123 I also log to the database. You should probably extract the logging configuration to a separate file, because it will get messy very quickly

Comment: you have right, but for first step i wanted to log events in different places. Thanks a lot again for your help and your time !!

Comment: @Fatman123 Note its also customary to upvote the post in addition to accepting, esp when its at this level of detail and helpfulness. (I upvoted for the exemplary patience on the getting the OP up to scratch). Upvoting the OP as it now meets the minimal requirement of the legwork a question should demonstrate - the intial downvote somebody did was well justified